# Differences of PowerShell window based on launch type

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Could someone explain differences of PowerShell window based on how I launch it?

1. Starting PowerShell from Start Menu default PowerShell shortcut to

   `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

   Font size and window color is normal.
2. Starting PowerShell from Run windows (Win + R)

   type `powershell` or `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

   Font size is bigger (window's size too) and window color is slightly different

Testing on fresh installation of Windows 10 1903 and 1909.

Comment: The shortcut file in the start menu contains specific configuration settings for the console host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what Mathias R. Jessen commented, if you look at the start menu version of powershell, you can see via rightclick -> open file location that the Start Menu version simply points to another shortcut which then points to %systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Now, if you rightclick that shortcut and go to, for example, Font, you can see it is configured to "14".

If you start powershell via run, rightclick the top bar -> defaults -> fonts, you can see the run-started instance of powershell uses the Font size 16.

Other than that, there is literally no difference, I just checked with a few extra steps whether it launches in elevated rights or if there is a difference in the powershell version, but nope. All the same.

Its just the config thats pushed with the extra shortcut.